# Google apps Script spreadsheet send mail as another address listed under "Send mail as:"

Tags: email, google-apps-script

In my google mail account, I have another few "send as" addresses. Obviously, all these were verified by google upon setting them up. 
Using google apps script in a spreadsheet, I need to send mail as one of those aliases instead of the default user name. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Have you read [the documentation about optional parameters](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendEmail%28String,String,String,Object%29) for the `MailApp.sendEmail()` method ?

Comment: Hi there. Thank you for your reply. Yes, I did read the documentation on the parameters, however, I did not find a way to be able to pick one address from  the addresses listed under my "Other emails" in my profile and pass it to MailApp.sendEmail() method.

Comment: Could you please rephrase your question to explain that this is what you're looking for?  Thanks.

Comment: Sure. Thanks for your patience. I was trying to enumerate all the e-mail addresses listed under my "Account"->Personal Info"-> "Other emails" and use one of them in a script. I used a bit more googling and it seems that I found the my answer: GmailApp.aliases() returns exactly that.